# How to disable auto "scroll to top" of UIWebView when a new request has finished loading?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview, scroll

How do I disable the default behavior of UIWebView where it automatically scrolls to top whenever a new request has finished loading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto scroll to top could happen maybe if you are tapping on the top bar (the black one)? In any case you can try to disable that feature -

`[yourWebView].scrollsToTop = NO;`

this should apply to `tableView` or `scrollView`